# jQModal or jQuery UI Dialog?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, modal-dialog

Seeking some advice as to whether use [jQModal window](http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/#examples) or instead use the jQuery UI Library for a modal window ?

The jQModal lib is only 2.4KB while the jQuery UI lib is like 32KB - generally all I am looking for is a modal window ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use jQuery UI modal.

- Official and well supported.
- jQuery UI and themes are [available on Google's CDN](http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html).
- You may want to use other parts of jQuery UI down the track.

But then again, if the filesize difference bothers you, just use the jQModal plugin. Bear in mind too that the jQuery UI on the CDN has a good chance of already being cached and therefore instantly available to the end user.

Comment: hey alex - yeah thanks a lot. i guess that the jQModal hasn't been updated in a while [09] so little concerned that it might not be again in the future. so perhaps your right jQuery UI is the better bet

Answer (score 1):

If you just want any old modal window, pick the smaller plugin file.  If that's not critical, then compare features.  Does one offer pleasing transitions that the other lacks?  Is it simple to style one versus the other?  Do the methods of one suit your style better than the other?  If all else is equal, pick the smaller file, but take a few minutes to compare them and consider your project.  There's probably a more compelling reason to pick one than just bytes, but you have to find it.

Comment: Hi Surreal - yeah after doing this - perhaps jQuery UI is better given that it will be continual developed in the future - whereas jQModal was depreciated a while back [ at least it seems ]

Comment: There you go, I knew you'd find the right choice for you.  :)